# Error in loop iteration: 'Loop must iterate over a collection type'

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

Please find my code here.

```
trigger PM1 on Account (after update) {
    List<Product_Metrics_vod__c> toDelete = new List<Product_Metrics_vod__c>();
    set<id> accsWithChangedRestrictions = new set<id>();
    for(Account acc : trigger.new){
        //if(acc.Restricted_Products_vod__c != trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).Restricted_Products_vod__c)
            accsWithChangedRestrictions.add(acc.id);
    }

list<Account> accs = [select Restricted_Products_vod__c,id, (select Products_vod__r.Name from Product_Metrics_vod__r) from Account where id in :accsWithChangedRestrictions];

for(Account acc : accs){
    for(Product_Metrics_vod__c av : acc){
        if(acc.Restricted_Products_vod__c.contains(av.Products_vod__r.Name)){
            //found a match
            toDelete.add(av);
        }
    }
}

delete toDelete;
```

}

> Error: Compile Error: Loop must iterate over a collection
>   type: SOBJECT:Account at line 12 column 41

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(Account acc : accs){
for(Product_Metrics_vod__c av : acc.Product_Metrics_vod__r){ //observe how to pull child records through the inner query
    if(acc.Restricted_Products_vod__c.contains(av.Products_vod__r.Name)){
        //found a match
        toDelete.add(av);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code should help you

Comment: Thanks Mohith!!!!I will keep it in mind next time!! Salesforce stack exchange is awesome!! Exponentially generating my interest in salesforce!!

Answer (score 2):

You did :

```
for(Account acc : accs){
    for(Product_Metrics_vod__c av : acc){
```

But `acc` is not a List but an `Account` and you can't iterate on it.

Try :

```
for(Account acc : accs){
        for(Product_Metrics_vod__c av : acc.Product_Metrics_vod__r){
```